# androidstudio Defalut activity not found when I use the aar which create by myself

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, aar

I have made an android `archive(.aar)` but when I use it in another project ,the androidstudio tip `default activity not found` I have tried many times but the question is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem at last. The minSdkVersion in the aar is higher than the project but AndroidStudio did not tip me very direct .